# Using Parse iOS SDK for web app too

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am creating an iOS app and using Parse as my backend. I may also want to create a web app version in the future too. Is there a way of using the current database in Parse used for the iOS app for a web app to save duplicating everything? If not, how else could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of the whole point of Parse. They offer iOS, Android, RESTful, etc API interfaces so you can connect to the data store from all of your front ends in exactly the same way (from a functionality standpoint).

Indeed, you iOS app doesn't need to use the provided iOS SDK, it could do everything via the REST interface if you wanted / needed to.

Answer (score 0):

yes offcourse you can connect Parse database to your web app. just go through https://parse.com/docs.